# How to snap object or cursor to solved track marker?

Tags: camera, tracking

Is there any option for snapping the cursor (or a object) to a selected camera track marker?

[image]

Comment: while it is selected press `Shift`+`S` and choose Cursor to Selected

Comment: Cool, thanks. I confused "Cursor to Selected" with "Cursor to Active" ;)

Comment: Hi. Please don't add "*Solved*" to your question or title. Instead we encourage you to post an answer below with a short description of the solution and what steps you took to reach it. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)